# Read file data from iOS image assets

Tags: ios, xcode, nsbundle, uiimageasset

How can I read the raw file data from iOS's image assets?

For example an "Image" imageset containing:

1. icon-1x.png
2. icon-2x.png
3. icon-3x.png

How do I use NSBundle or other methods to load the raw PNG file data (not to decode the image data) of, for example, icon-1x.png?

Comment: is that icon-1x.png same for icon-2x or different images?

Comment: @AntonyRaphel different

Comment: Here is a working example of wrapping binary data up into a PNG IDAT set of chunks and then converting back to a raw data buffer. https://stackoverflow.com/q/56267037/763355

Answer (score 0):

store the image with name icon-1x.png, icon-2x.png and icon-3x.png in image set.then try with like this loop,

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon-%dx.png", i];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
    NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img); // Convert it in to PNG data
}
```

otherwise you can get from tag of the imageView. then pass that tag value like this:

```
NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"icon-%dx.png", imageView.tag];
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(img); // Convert it in to PNG data
```

Comment: This does not help me because it does not give me the PNG data (like opening a file), but rather it decodes the image.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solve my problem. The UIImagePNGRepresentation function converts the in-memory bitmap to PNG, which is different then the PNG bytes from the file. :)

Comment: then what kind of format do you want? base64 string?